# How is free expansion within the system different from free expansion across the system?

Tags: thermodynamics, work

Consider the case where a chamber is divided into 2 halves with a chamber in the middle. The left of the membrane has gas, the right is vacuum. If I consider the whole chamber as my system, there is no heat or work transit across the boundary, thus work done by the gas is zero when the chamber is removed.

If I considered just the vacuum part as my system, the first gas particle entering from the left region does no work as there is no resisting force to it. But as the second particle enters, it has the resisting force of the first particle. Thus the work done when the gas totally enters the vacuum is not zero.

So, work done by gas depends on the system we choose. Why is the statement "Work done by gas when expanded in vacuum is zero" generalised?

There is pressure difference in the system if we choose the whole chamber as our system. Thus, there is no mechanical equilibrium. Then how is choosing the whole chamber for thermodynamic analysis valid?

Can we plot the free expansion of gas on P-V diagram?

Comment: "So, work done depends on the system we choose". Well yeah, obviously, right? That's always the case.

Comment: Yes it is,then why is the free expansion statement generalised?

Comment: There is no macroscopic work made by the gas as it expands, and any interactions you call work ends up back in the gas itself, so that the internal energy of the gas remains constant

Answer (score 1):

> If i consider the whole chamber as my system,there is no heat or work
>   transit across the boundary,thus work done by the gas is zero when the
>   chamber is removed.

If the chamber is rigid, has perfectly thermally insulated walls, and no openings, then it is an isolated system and there can be no mass or any form of energy transfer between the system and its surroundings. When the boundary is removed within this isolated system, there is no energy transfer in the form of heat or work between the system and its surroundings based on how you defined your system.

> If i considered just the vaccum part as my system,the first gas
>   particle entering from the left region does no work as there is no
>   resisting force to it.But as the second particle enters it has the
>   resisiting force of the first particle.Thus the work done when the gas
>   totally enters the vaccum is not zero.

You are now redefining your system as just the vacuum part of the chamber. This means the part of the chamber with the gas is now part of your surroundings. Everything outside the entire chamber is also part of the surrounding, but your newly defined system is isolated from that part so it need not be considered.

Now for your redefined system you cans say that the surroundings (part of chamber initially filled with all of the gas) is doing work on the system (part of the chamber initially evacuated). Then there will be energy transfer (work) between the system and its surroundings. But for conservation of energy, the energy transferred out of the surroundings has to  exactly equal the energy transferred into the system, since both are isolated from everything outside the chamber. Taken together the change in internal energy of the system + surroundings (total contents of the chamber) is zero.

> So,work done by gas depends on the system we choose.Why is the
>   statement "Work done by gas when expanded in vaccum is
>   zero"generalised?

Since by definition work is energy transfer between a system and its surroundings, clearly work will depend on how you define the system and its surroundings.

> There is pressure difference in the system if we choose the whole
>   chamber as our system. Thus, there is no mechanical equilibrium. Then
>   how is choosing the whole chamber for thermodynamic analysis valid?

The "system" is technically the gas in the chamber. Before removing the barrier between the gas and the vacuum side, the gas is in mechanical and thermal equilibrium. That is, there are no pressure or temperature gradients in the gas. It is no different than a gas in a cylinder fitted with a piston that is locked in place. Just because the gas in the cylinder may initially be at a higher or lower pressure than the environment outside the cylinder does not mean the gas in not in mechanical equilibrium. As long as there are *no pressure gradients within the gas itself*, it is in mechanical equilibrium.

But if the locked piston is abruptly unlocked, the gas begins to rapidly expand or contract. Now there are pressure gradients within the gas and it is not in mechanical equilibrium.

> can we plot the free expansion of gas on P-V diagarm?

If we can assume ideal gas behavior, we can only plot the end points. This is because the free expansion is an irreversible process (happens very quickly) and does not proceed through a series of equilibrium states. Since the change in internal energy of the contents of the chamber is zero, and the internal energy of an ideal gas depends only on temperature, the initial and final temperatures are the same. Therefore, from the ideal gas law where $i$ and $f$ denote initial and final conditions, we have.

$$P_{f}V_{f}=P_{i}V_{i}$$

This allows us to plot the two end points on the P-V diagram.

But since we cannot plot any points in between, we cannot determine the work done because that would be the area under the P-V curve. However, we can determine the work that *could have been done* on the surroundings had the expansion been a reversible (very slow) one.

To do this, we replace the barrier with a piston connected to force external to the chamber, remove the chamber thermal insulation, and perform a reversible isothermal compression to return the system to its original state. The magnitude of the isothermal compression work is then the magnitude of the isothermal expansion work that could have been done by the gas in a reversible isothermal expansion. This represents the lost opportunity to do external work due to the irreversible expansion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes,but my question is why is the statement generalised?

Comment: @Krishna Deshmukh exactly what do you mean by “generalized”?

Comment: It is wrtten in many books,just, without any mention that it is just a special case!

Comment: can we plot the free expansion of gas on P-V diagarm?

Comment: @KrishnaDeshmukh Only the end points, not the path between. But that is an excellent follow up question. I will revise my answer to address it. Please stand by

Comment: @KrishnaDeshmukh I have revised my answer in response to your follow up question. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer ..there is another question unanswered.Please answer it.

Comment: @KrishnaDeshmukh I'm sorry I didn't realize there was a question unanswered. I just now saw your comment. I have updated my answer to respond. It is the second to last highlighted statement. Hope this acceptably answers your question completely.